# How can I track the reason why FS is included by emscripten?

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I am compiling some C++ code to emscripten. I noticed that emscripten includes a large piece of code to support file-system manipulation. According to emscripten's documentation, this code is included because the compiled C++ invokes I/O functions. Otherwise, it would not be there. This is the relevant part of the documentation:

> Emscripten decides whether to include file system support
>   automatically. Many programs don’t need files, and file system support
>   is not negligible in size, so Emscripten avoids including it when it
>   doesn’t see a reason to. That means that if your C/C++ code does not
>   access files, then the FS object and other file system APIs will not
>   be included in the output. And, on the other hand, if your C/C++ code
>   does use files, then file system support will be automatically
>   included. So normally things will “just work” and you don’t need to
>   think about this at all.

The code I am compiling should not be doing I/O, and I would like to optimize the size of the compiled javascript. I tried hard to remove all I/O code, but there must be something left somewhere that requires FS support.

Is there a simple way I could track what requires FS support in my code?

Comment: Search the code base for `ifstream` and `ofstream`?

Comment: I did that already. I am quite sure there is no C++ stream in the code. I also defined NDEBUG to disable the output of asserts. It seems there are still references to stdout stdin or stderr somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way I could track what requires FS support in my code?

The only way I can think of is to repeatedly "bisect" the code. Comment out roughly half of it, in a way that still compiles, and check if the output has the filesystem code. If no, the commented out half is causing the issue. If yes, the non-commented half is (perhaps not exclusively) causing the issue. You take the half that is causing the issue, and repeat.

This way you can try to "zoom in" on that part(s) that causes the FS code to be included.

I've used a similar method in the past to zoom in on linker errors on a large C++ code base that was unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Thanks again. I will do this, although I'd love to have a simpler solution.

Comment: For the record, I found that `std::random_device` is what caused FS to be included. Maybe someone trying to solve the same problem might find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `NO_FILESYSTEM` compiler option, as explained at https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/optimizing/Optimizing-Code.html#miscellaneous-code-size-tips

> You can use the NO_FILESYSTEM option to disable bundling of filesystem support code (the compiler should optimize it out if not used, but may not always succeed). This can be useful if you are building a pure computational library, for example. See settings.js for more details.

Which you use on the command line as

```
emcc -s NO_FILESYSTEM=1 [... other stuff]
```

Comment: That helped, but I'd really like to know why FS is included in the output. I suppose it is invoked somewhere in my code, and if this code ever gets executed, then the javascript will crash at run time.

Comment: Ah sorry, I realise I answered a slightly different question to the one you asked!